# How can I make this model?

Tags: 3d-models

Here's the model I'm trying to print, [Truncated Icosahedron](https://www.shapeways.com/product/DX4FZNAUW/truncated-icosahedron?optionId=8435791)

[image: Truncated Icosahedron]

But it must be 12" in diameter and gray in color `rgb = #444444`

I also want two of the hexagons to be yellow in color: `rgb = #FFFF00`

Similar to [this photo](http://i68.tinypic.com/altceq.jpg):

[image: Coloured hexagon]

How to do this? I don't seem to be able to edit the shape on shapeways.

---

#### UPDATE

Got it.

[skeleton bucky ball](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:308179/#files)

Comment: I haven't tried anything other than try and find a model from the internet. I've never used 3D modelling software...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any restrictions to your methodology, your objective is easily accomplished. Thingiverse has a [truncated icosahedron model](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:608201) available for download and printing.

[image: icosahedron]

Because the creator has included in the download the OpenSCAD source files, you could edit it to meet your bed limitations. I've downloaded the source, opened it and found the model is a single hexagon, until you change a parameter from 6 to 5 to get a pentagon. I suspect the assembly is up to the builder to figure out.

It appears that the default is for a 50 mm diameter sphere. Change the 50 in the code to 300 or so to reach your 12" desired diameter.

An alternative to friction welding would be just about any decent epoxy or even a 3D printing pen such as the 3Doodler.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your suggestion. It's very useful, thanks. I will try and find a .stl file from somewhere.

Comment: The link in my message directs you to an STL and the OpenSCAD source, which allows you to create any shape you desire. Even if you've never used modeling software, the OpenSCAD source will be easy enough to learn, especially with the small amount of code involved. Summary: Change diameter from 50 to something (or not), press F5 to preview. Change facets from 6 to 5, press F5 to preview. Press F6 to render, then save STL file for printing. It's that easy.